# java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [/data/nroot/client_key.p12] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have updated the Spring-rabbit version from 1.7 to 2.2.8 to support SSL connection. the below exception is throwing when i mentioned external paths to key store & trust store i.e., outside the jar file.

```
2:40:53,853 |-ERROR in com.axon.log.dropwizard.AxonAMQPAppender[rabbitmq] - Failed to create customized Rabbit ConnectionFactory. org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [/data/nroot/client_key.p12] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [/data/nroot/client_key.p12] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:70)
    at     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean.setUpSSL(RabbitConnectionFactoryBean.java:743)
    at     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean.createInstance(RabbitConnectionFactoryBean.java:706)
    at     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean.createInstance(RabbitConnectionFactoryBean.java:80)
    at     at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:142)
    at     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(RabbitConnectionFactoryBean.java:691)
    at     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.logback.AmqpAppender.createRabbitConnectionFactory(AmqpAppender.java:710)
    at     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.logback.AmqpAppender.start(AmqpAppender.java:675)
    at     at com.axon.log.dropwizard.AmqpAppenderFactory.build(AmqpAppenderFactory.java:373)
    at     at io.dropwizard.logging.DefaultLoggingFactory.configure(DefaultLoggingFactory.java:143)
    at     at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:83)
    at     at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at     at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
    at     at com.infa.products.axon.bulkupload.BulkUploadApplication.main(BulkUploadApplication.java:62)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [/data/nroot/client_key.p12] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at     at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean.configureKeyManagers(RabbitConnectionFactoryBean.java:776)
    at     at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean.setUpSSL(RabbitConnectionFactoryBean.java:725)
    at     ... 12 common frames omitted
12:40:53,853 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[async-rabbitmq] - Attaching appender named [rabbitmq] to AsyncAppender.
12:40:53,853 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[async-rabbitmq] - Setting discardingThreshold to 51
```

i have updated only spring-rabbit to 2.2.8.RELEASE. i have tried to update dependencies to latest, but ran into couple of other issues. then i have updated only spring-rabbit version to support SSL connection.

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
        compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
        compile group: 'io.dropwizard', name: 'dropwizard-logging', version: '1.1.0'
        compile group: 'net.logstash.logback', name: 'logstash-logback-encoder', version: '4.11'
        compile group: 'ch.qos.logback.contrib', name: 'logback-json-classic', version: '0.1.2'
        compile group: 'ch.qos.logback.contrib', name: 'logback-jackson', version: '0.1.5'
        compile group: 'org.springframework.amqp', name: 'spring-rabbit', version: '2.2.8.RELEASE'
        compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
        compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.8.0'
        compile group: 'org.bitbucket.b_c', name: 'jose4j', version: '0.5.5'
    }
```

YML config entry:

```
- type: rabbitmq
          host: localhost
          port: 5671
          username: guest
          password: =AXON:CIPHER:AES:128=CrYVHt53/OWVCgAXXrrZ2ufouJwnIdKQzF9VQlSR7NaDE1XpEGPyCznCL57Gpx+RKhrIKR+ytURDzrPv7qw8Rw==
          exchange: axon_log_java
          routingKey: log_routing_key
          appName: Unison
          enabled: true
          secure: true
          tlsVersion: TLSv1.2
          keyStorePassword: MySecretPassword
          trustStorePassword: MySecretPassword
          clientKeyPath: /data/nroot/client_key.p12
          trustStorePath: /data/nroot/rabbitstore
          keyStoreType: PKCS12
          trustStoreType: JKS
          verifyHostname: false
```

==========
Yml properties setting to AMQPAppender:

@JsonTypeName("rabbitmq")
public class AmqpAppenderFactory extends AbstractAppenderFactory {
........
..............
...........

```
@Override
public Appender build(LoggerContext context, String applicationName, LayoutFactory layoutFactory, LevelFilterFactory levelFilterFactory, AsyncAppenderFactory asyncAppenderFactory) {
    JsonLayout layout = new JsonLayout();
    layout.setJsonFormatter(new JacksonJsonFormatter());
    layout.setAppendLineSeparator(true);
    layout.setTimestampFormatTimezoneId("UTC");
    layout.setIncludeContextName(includeContextName);
    //LayoutWrappingEncoder<ILoggingEvent> layoutEncoder = new LayoutWrappingEncoder<>();
    //layoutEncoder.setLayout(layout);

    final AxonAMQPAppender amqpAppender= new AxonAMQPAppender();
    amqpAppender.setName(appenderName);
    amqpAppender.setContext(context);
    amqpAppender.setLayout(layout);
    amqpAppender.setDeclareExchange(isDeclareExchange());
    amqpAppender.setVirtualHost(getVHost());
    amqpAppender.setHost(getHost());
    amqpAppender.setContentType("application/json");
    amqpAppender.setDurable(isDurable());
    amqpAppender.setGenerateId(isGenerateId());
    amqpAppender.setExchangeType(getExchangeType());
    amqpAppender.setMaxSenderRetries(getMaxRetry());
    amqpAppender.setPassword(getPassword());
    amqpAppender.setUsername(getUsername());
    amqpAppender.setPort(getPort());
    amqpAppender.setRoutingKeyPattern(getRoutingKey());
    amqpAppender.setExchangeName(getExchange());
    amqpAppender.setApplicationId(getAppName());
    amqpAppender.addFilter(levelFilterFactory.build(threshold));
    **amqpAppender.setUseSsl(isSecure());
    amqpAppender.setSslAlgorithm(getTlsVersion());
    amqpAppender.setKeyStore(getClientKeyPath());
    amqpAppender.setKeyStorePassphrase(getKeyStorePassword());
    amqpAppender.setKeyStoreType(getKeyStoreType());
    amqpAppender.setTrustStore(getTrustStorePath());
    amqpAppender.setTrustStorePassphrase(getTrustStorePassword());
    amqpAppender.setTrustStoreType(getTrustStoreType());
    amqpAppender.setVerifyHostname(isVerifyHostname());**

    String command = System.getProperty("centralized.logging");

    if(false == getEnabled() || "false".equals(command)){

        NullAppender nullAppender = new NullAppender();
        nullAppender.setContext(context);
        return wrapAsync(nullAppender,asyncAppenderFactory);
    }
    **amqpAppender.start();**
    return wrapAsync(amqpAppender,asyncAppenderFactory);
}
```

}

AMQPAppender class:

```
public class AxonAMQPAppender extends AmqpAppender {
    
        public static String APP_ID = "";
        public static String SOURCE = "";
    
        @Override
        public Message postProcessMessageBeforeSend(Message message, Event event)
        {
            String body = new String(message.getBody());
            //some line of code
            return message;
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved my issue.

By default its look for classpath or if we specify classpath: i.e., ClasspathResourceLoader
for external file paths need to specify file: i.e., its usesFileUrlResourceLoader